# Unbind CUA <C-return> key only in dired mode

Tags: key-bindings, dired, use-package, emacs-w32

Goal: unbind `<C-return>` key ONLY in `dired mode` in order to rebind it to `dired-w32explore`.
My configuration is using `use-package` with something like this:

```
(use-package dired
  :init
  (unbind-key "<C-return>" cua-global-keymap)
  :bind (:map dired-mode-map
              ("<C-return>" . dired-w32explore))
```

The key works in `dired-mode` as I want.
But I get the CUA key completely removed in the rest of modes.
Is it possible to unbind that key only for `dired-mode`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so following Drew's answer, I came across with these lines:

```
(defun special-c-return-in-dired ()
  (interactive)
  (if (derived-mode-p 'dired-mode)
      (dired-w32explore)
    (cua-set-rectangle-mark))
  )

(define-key cua-global-keymap [C-return] 'special-c-return-in-dired)
```

That works for me!
Thanks Drew!

Answer (score 0):

`cua-mode` is a minor mode, so its keymap takes precedence over major-mode keymaps.

You can explicitly turn off `cua-mode` in `dired-mode-hook`, but you would then need to explicitly turn it on in other major modes where you want it on.

Alternatively, you can bind `<C-return>` in `cua-global-keymap` to your own command that checks `(derived-mode-p 'dired-mode)` and in that case invokes `dired-w32explore` and otherwise invokes `cua-set-rectangle-mark`.

Comment: Thank you @Drew! I wrote some lines and it works.